# Force dark mode in Android Glance widget

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, glance-appwidget

Is there a way to force dark mode in Android Glance widgets? I have a setting in the app that allows locking the mode to light or dark, and I would like the widget to respect it too.